# Android Firebase PERMISSION_DENIED reason API_KEY_SERVICE_BLOCKED

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I ran into such a problem, when I tried to initialize firebase and get the FCM token, I get this error, who faced it? What could be the reason? A month ago, everything worked, after that nothing was changed in google-services.json file, firebase flow in project, or in google console.
[image]

API key permissions added

[image]

Comment: have you checked the `security rules` for `firebase`

Comment: what is it? Where i can find it? And what I need to see there?

Comment: for example have you set anything like this in the rules section in firebase ? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was on key, idk why, but when I set new key, all ok.

20.05.2022 Better to use Android apps restrictions now.

Comment: That probably worked because you are using a new different key, but previous one for sure was restricted in Google Cloud

Comment: Maybe you compile it using a new computer. You have to add the new generated SHA1 key on Credentials which generated by Firebase.

Answer (score 2):

In our case, this happened when we added a new Firebase library to our project (Performance Monitoring). Our API key is restricted to only allow certain APIs to work, as suggested by Google.

Log in to the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?folder), and make sure you're allowing the API to work with your restricted key. In this specific case, you need to allow the Firebase Installations API.

Once I added that and waited about 10 minutes, this error stopped and the Firebase tools are working as expected with our app.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed same error while adding push notifications into iOS project:

Fixed on `Google Cloud console` -> `APIs & Services` -> `Credentials`

[image: Google Cloud - Credentials image]

then CLICK on the API Key you are using for the app having problems

[image]

Scroll to the API restrictions section

[image: api restrictions section]

expand the combo box and select `Firebase Cloud Messaging API` and `Firebase Installations API`  hit `OK` after selecting both and `SAVE` this.

[image]

`REMEMBER: Wait 5 to 10 minutes to test this working, so be patient and grab a coffee before testing again :)`

Comment: Thanks for your step-by-step guide. Unfortunately, enabling those two keys didn't work for me and I still have an issue with authentication after an hour. So, I decided to enable the "Don't restrict key" option. It fixed my problem temporarily until I find the proper key that needs to be enabled.